# Which bypass cap position creates a cleaner voltage and current feedback circuit?

Tags: noise, current-measurement, voltage-measurement, bypass-capacitor

Is the following true? Caps = 2, 1800 uF Nichicon, Manf Num UHE1V182MHD3, CAP ALUM 1800UF 20% 35V RADIAL. [image]

"you want your bypass caps as close to what you are bypassing with the least series resistance possible. See attached sketch. If you have your shunt resistor down stream of your bypass caps the the system will have voltage ripple or noise on it due to the voltage generated by current accross the shunt resistors. Look at the data sheet for the caps, they have an ESR of 26mohms. With the shunt resistor you are adding almost 50% more ESR. Plus you have a diode drop between the bypass caps.  You are killing the effectiveness of you bypass caps with the shunt resistor and diodes. ESR is one of the most critical items for bypassing."

Comment: Which end generates the noise? The question doesn't tell us if you have a noisy supply and a quiet resistive load, or a quiet supply and a noisy load.

Comment: Thanks for asking! The input is switchable 120 or 240 VAC 240 Watt power supply that spits out 27.5 VDC. This is pretty clean. The noise comes from the 3 half bridge FETs which control the BLDC motor. So it is noisy on load side. Which after typing all that I just realized I now agree the right circuit is better also. Great question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a word - yes. The purpose of the bypass capacitor is to keep the voltage across the load stable by providing a local energy store which can satisfy AC current demands without causing ripple in the voltage across the load. Since V=IR, the higher the resistance between the bypass capacitor and the load, the higher the ripple voltage that will develop across the load.

Moving the capacitor closer to the load (as shown in the right hand side of the diagram) means that current supplied by the capacitor will not have to flow through the current sense resistor, and hence less ripple voltage will be observed. Depending on the amount of ripple you're talking about here, you should be able to easily observe this with an AC-coupled scope probe across the load.

Comment: Just to clarify, we are at 27 VDC and looking for the cleanest possible reading at the voltage and current circuit. Does that affect your answer?

Comment: No - that's still the way I would do it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can you discuss how this changes when you want to place bypass caps as close to an IC as possible?

Comment: Those follow the same principle - closer to the IC means shorter traces between the capacitor and the IC. That means lower resistance (and inductance) and hence lower ripple voltage.

Comment: Following that theory, wouldn't I want them closer to the ic of current and voltage circuit? The load gets trashed and noisy anyway as it goes through the FETs to the bldc motor

Comment: You would generally put a large bulk capacitor like those mentioned in the question near the high current load and smaller ceramic decoupling caps near ICs to provide each with a local power store.

Comment: You feel the larger bulk cap wouldn't do a good of job cleaning the noise as the smaller ceramic decoupling caps?

Comment: They are at different points in the circuit doing different jobs. Small ceramic caps close to ICs are used to decouple their supply - the large bulk cap is there to keep the load voltage decoupled. Depending on the noise frequency, sometimes capacitor combinations are used, each aimed at a particular band. This is now veering off-topic - if you have further questions please either rephrase the original question or ask a new one if your answers cannot be found elsewhere on the site.